# Android app isExpired false, while backend verification shows expired time

Tags: android, token

I'm verifying token for android on backend (java) like this:

```
        GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier =
                new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new GsonFactory())
                        .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(googleClientAppID))
                        .build();
...
        GoogleidToken idToken = verifier.verify(googleIdToken);
        if (idToken == null) {
            return false;
        }

...
```

I get false, meaning that verification failed.

At the same time at android application the following code won't enter if statement:

```
        GoogleSignInAccount glAccount = 
        GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());
        if (glAccount != null && glAccount.isExpired()) {
            //com.google.api.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().reloadAuthResponse();
            glAccount = null;
        }
```

so token is not expired.

After checking the code and what it does in case of android application the check is:

```
        return zaf.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L >= this.zal - 300L;
```

which is ok, not expired, whatever those zaf/zal values means.

now the backend check is like this (showing code that returns false, making it as expired):

```
        this.verifyExpirationTime(currentTimeMillis, acceptableTimeSkewSeconds)
```

verifyExpirationTime does this:

```
        return currentTimeMillis <= (this.getPayload().getExpirationTimeSeconds() + acceptableTimeSkewSeconds) * 1000L;
```

Now i wonder why they differ? Looks like payload of the token contains expiration time in seconds that says token is expired.
What am i doing wrong?

I've checked time on backend server its ok (correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a problem of time that was set incorrectly on the android emulator. Fixing time to correct one removed this issue.